# How to fetch value from MySQL table based on array value using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need one help .I need to fetch values from Database but it should depends on some data present inside an array using PHP and Mysql.I am explaining my code below.

```
$arr=['1','2','4','5','12','13'];
```

The above array has some value which is also present inside table as one column which is given below.

> db_user:

```
id    name    supplier_id    city


1    Rocky     1             bbsr

2    Raj       4             CTC

3    Moynk     6             bLS

4    Nilima    1              CTC


5   Biswa      2             BBSR

6   Deepak     12            NPR

7   Rajua      13            OMP

8   Girija      10           CTC

9   Joyes      2            KKR
```

In the above table the array value are present inside column `supplier_id` here i need query to fetch all values whose `supplier_id` are belongs to that array and that also in descending order.Please help me.

Comment: please post your SELECT query

Comment: My guess is that @subhra doesn't know what a SELECT is... SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE supplier_id=X OR supplier_id=Y OR ... OR supplier_id=Z ORDER BY supplier_id DESC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an `IN` clause for this. First of all take your array and implode it on `,` so you get a list of numbers you want to search against. Then provide that list to that `IN` clause and get your results.

```
$arr=['1','2','4','5','12','13'];
$values=implode(",",$arr);
$query="SELECT * FROM db_user WHERE supplier_id IN ($values) ORDER BY supplier_id DESC";
```

Now run that query

Comment: This is a better query than mine.